# Huge delay when running networking commands

Tags: raspbian, networking

For some reason, it takes from 5 to 10 minutes just to run a networking related command such as `ifconfig` or `iwconfig`. Sometimes this happens on startup, sometimes this happens after a couple of hours.

My `top` output can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/ZL1LdxXt).

Comment: Can you type top, or install htop by sudo apt-get install htop and add the content to your question

Comment: Do other, non-network tasks take as long? Have you looked at the system logs? I've had similar problems when my filesystem was corrupt and found my logs full of errors.

Comment: Have a look at `tail /var/log/syslog` when this happens.

Comment: @bobstro No, `top` worked fine.

Comment: You can install strace and run `strace ifconfig`. See at what system call the tool hangs.

Comment: @goldilocks a bunch of `Jul 19 17:14:02 raspberrypi kernel: [ 363.746769] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00usb_vendor_request: Error: - Vendor Request 0x07 failed for offset 0x101c with error -32`

Comment: @Joffrey `ioctl(4, SIOCGIFCONF, {`

Comment: Hmmm -- there are certain kinds of hardware error that the kernel can't extract itself from easily once they occur.  Kind of sounds like that.   Wifi adapter problems on the pi are often power supply related; they may not occur until the system is under sufficient load.   What are the volts/amps of your supply?   Do you have another, beefier one you could test against?

Comment: @goldilocks 5VDC 2A, these are the most powerful in my house, but I do own a powered USB hub. would that help?

Comment: @robbie0630: also, check the usb cable... a bad usb cable can cause a significant voltage drop.

Comment: If it's the wifi adapter and at most one other USB device, 2 A should be enough, but as Joffrey points out there are some potential "weak links" involved.   This kind of gear is mostly intended to pass muster with people recharging things or connecting <= 500 mA devices.   So you want to rule that possibility out by using two *different* (as in, not identical) but sufficient supplies and if applicable a few different cables too.   If that doesn't solve the problem, then it's likely something to do with the driver; you'd need to try a different adapter.

Comment: @goldilocks I actually have used a different adapter in the past, the same problem happened. I'll try some different cables, see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @robbie0630 - Have you updated the OS and firmware to the latest? Are you running raspbian? What sort of USB wifi adapter are you using? Do you see a little 4 color square at the top-right of your display?